# How to chain NInject modules together

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a multitier application using NInject to resolve dependency injection. Each tier has a particular NInject module:

```
Service Layer - ServiceModule
DataLayer - DataModule
```

In my presentation layer I really dont want to load every single module. Instead of that I want, for an example, load the ServiceModule and the module is responsible to load its dependencies.

How can I achieve that?

For example here is my ServiceModule:

```
public class ServicesModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        ...
        Bind<IProductService>().To<ProductService>();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simple, inside a NInject module you can access the kernel:

```
Kernel.Load(new [] { new [YourModule]() });
```

Comment: If you bring in the Ninject namespace by adding `using Ninject;` you will also get an extension method that provides a `Kernel.Load` method that makes it even easier... `Kernel.Load(params INinjectModule[] modules);`.

Comment: Is there a non-custom way to avoid multiple module initialization when there are shared modules present in the module hierarchy? Suppose I have module `A` that depends on module `C` and module `B` that depends on module `C`. If I call `Kernel.Load(C)` in both `A` and `B`, Ninject will yell at me saying that module C is already initialized.

Answer (score -2):

If your module has a single module it depends on, you can inherit from that module (instead of `NinjectModule`) and call `base.Load()`:

```
public override void Load()
{
    base.Load();
    ...
}
```

This will effectively chain the modules.

Comment: Allthough im not yet that familiar with Ninject, inheriting in general always implies an *is Relation*. What the OP wants is an *association* from `ServiceModule` to `DataModule`